# Post photo without login

Tags: facebook, post, photo

Is it real to post photo without any login to FB account ? I read about access_token and it work pervfect with simple wall post message, but when i tey to post photo with access_token without login ti FB i get always error. Help me please.

```
    <?php

    ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    require 'facebook-php-sdk-master/src/facebook.php';

    $photo = 'mma.jpg'; 
    $message = 'TEST MESSAGE';

    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'  => 'APP ID',
        'secret' => 'APP_SECRET',
        'fileUpload' => true,
        'cookie' => true,
    ));

    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
        'canvas' => 1,
        'fbconnect' => 0,
        'scope' => 'offline_access,publish_stream,photo_upload'
    ));

    $user = $facebook->getUser();
    if($user){
        echo $facebook->getAccessToken();
    }
    $tokenac = $facebook->getAccessToken();


    $post =  array(
        'access_token' => "$tokenac",
        'message' => 'Test post' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),

    );


    $res = $facebook->api('/10000******8933/feed', 'POST', $post);
    echo 'ID: ',$res['id'];
```

i tried like this, but it dont work. Can anyone help please

```
require 'facebook-php-sdk-master/src/facebook.php'; 

$photo = 'mma.jpg';
$message = 'Nope, this message last after 10:2222 (test)'; 

$facebook = new Facebook(
    array(
    'appId'  => '646351572060837',
    'secret' => 'e4215791489cce26778ed02403a04427',
    'fileUpload' => true, 
    'cookie' => true,
    )
);

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
    array(
    'canvas' => 1,
    'fbconnect' => 0,
    'scope' => 'offline_access,publish_stream,photo_upload'
    )
);


$tokenac = $facebook->getAccessToken(); 


$res = $facebook->api(
    '/100001776698933/photos', 'POST', 
    array(
        'access_token' => $tokenac,
        'source' => '@' . $photo,
        'message' => $message,
    )
);
echo 'ID: ',$res['id'];
```

always with photo get this error, 
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: A user access token is required to request this resource. thrown in base_facebook.php on line 1254

Comment: That any can go for example in my web admin, choose photo and it will publicated on facebook page.

Comment: You are calling the method getLoginURL, but you are not _doing_ anything with the login URL it returns – you have to redirect the user to that URL in order to have them presented with the login screen. And `offline_access` is not available any more, remove it from your permissions scope you are asking for.

Comment: But for what then i take access token ? ill dont want to manual login to fb, i wanna make it automatic with access token. Or i didnt understand somethink ?) Can i post photo automatic from any pc, without acc login like in first code where i post message to wall ? Sorry bad english

Comment: Without login in the `getAccessToken` method will only generate an _app_ access token, whereas you want to use a _user_ access token.

Comment: So i need to take access_token when i was logined, and then i can use this token to publicate without login ?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Comment: Okay, thanks ! But mby you know this problem ? Now i get other access token when was loggined, but now i get this error
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#100) Invalid fbid. thrown in base_facebook.php on line 1254
Mby you know fast solution

Comment: Main question, is it real to publicate without login , without any acc data, just run script and publicate to fb wall photo ?

Answer (score 0):

Posting from a user account, needs a valid access token, which means you need to login.

In the PHP SDK, if no login is supplied it defaults to the application access token which is **not** a valid user access token for posting to photos.

Use a login flow https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/

Comment: Thanks, with post facebook status all work, i getting access token which dont expires and all work perfect. But how about posting photo, how i understood i need other access token which i can took only after login but it expires after 1 hour. Somewhere i saw that i can change access token to other when it expires, is it real ?

Comment: For example, there i can manual took this token, and all work perfect, but only 1 hour. How i can automate take or change this token to other which will +1 hour or mby i can took infinite token ?